# STS - ExpiredTokenException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am using STS in a Lambda function in Account A to AssumeRole in another account Account B to Put Records in a Kinesis Stream in Account B.

Below is the code that I have in Lambda function for Cross Account Kinesis Access

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumedRoleObject = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn=CROSS_ACC_KINESIS_ROLE, RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1")
credentials = assumedRoleObject['Credentials']

kinesis_cross_acc_client = boto3.client(
'kinesis', 
aws_access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId'], 
aws_secret_access_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'], 
aws_session_token = credentials['SessionToken'], 
region_name=CROSS_ACC_KINESIS_REGION)
```

I do keep on getting 
**ClientError
An error occurred (ExpiredTokenException) when calling the PutRecords operation: The security token included in the request is expired**

I thought that when Lambda runs, it should be able to get the Token again and again, so I wouldnt need to refresh it. 
Also by default, the STS token expires after 3600 seconds. The lambda cant run for that long.

How do I check if the Token has expired and refresh it ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: This error also means that you do not have permission or "trust" to assume the role. Did you setup the Trust Policy giving Lamdba permission to assume this role in the other account?

Comment: Yes. It works most of the time. Just fails with this error once in a while

Comment: Try logging current time and the token expiration: credentials['Expiration'].isoformat(). Compare times that the token works versions times that it does not.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will find expiration in the credentials variable you created.

credentials `credentials['Expiration']`

Answer (score 0):

On every Lambda run, I check for the Expiration and then use that to determine if the STS Token needs to be refreshed.

```
time_left = int(
        credentials['Expiration'].timestamp() - datetime.now().timestamp()
    )
    logger.info('STS Timeleft: {}'.format(time_left))
    # If time left is less than 5 minutes, refresh
    if time_left < 300:
        assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
            RoleArn=CROSS_ACC_KINESIS_ROLE,
            RoleSessionName='AssumeRoleSession1'
        )
        credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']
        logger.info("STS renewed. New Time: {}".format(
            credentials['Expiration']
        ))
        kinesis_cross_acc_client = boto3.client(
            'kinesis',
            aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
            aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
            aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
            region_name=CROSS_ACC_KINESIS_REGION
        )
```